C++ Visitor Pattern with Variant Return Type and Accumulated State
I am trying to build computations against a well defined set of types, much like you would get in a database or dataframe computation library. Given the types are limited but the algorithms are infinite, I figured the visitor pattern is the right design choice.
Another design consideration is that the type returned by the visitors may vary. For example, if I started with a variant of different integral widths, a "summation" algorithm may return a 64 bit integer for all variant types. However, a "min" algorithm may respect the type that is being visited.
Here's a theoretical foundation for the design, with a FooVisitor that returns the same type that is being visited (here the actual value being returned is unimportant)
#include <cstdint>

#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

using ScalarT = std::variant<int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, float, double>;

struct FooVisitor {
  auto operator()(int8_t) { return ScalarT{int8_t{0}}; }
  auto operator()(int16_t) { return ScalarT{int16_t{1}}; }
  auto operator()(int32_t) { return ScalarT{int32_t{2}}; }
  auto operator()(int64_t) { return ScalarT{int64_t{4}}; }  
  auto operator()(float) { return ScalarT{float{8}}; }
  auto operator()(double) { return ScalarT{double{16}}; }
};

int main() {
  auto v1 = ScalarT{int8_t{}};
  auto foo = std::visit(FooVisitor(), v1);
  std::cout << "First index is: " << foo.index() << std::endl;

  auto v2 = ScalarT{int32_t{}};
  auto bar = std::visit(FooVisitor(), v2);  
  std::cout << "Second index is: " << bar.index() << std::endl;  
}

What I am struggling with conceptually is how to structure my visitors so that they may be able to visit different values of the same type, accumulating results along the way before adding one last method that can reduce the accumulated values to a scalar (here Finalize). The purpose of this is to allow for dealing with datasets that are potentially larger than memory and need to be computed in chunks.
So something along the lines of:
#include <cstdint>

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using ScalarT = std::variant<int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, float, double>;

class FooVisitor {
public:
  auto operator()(int8_t) { values_seen_.emplace_back(ScalarT{int8_t{0}}); }
  auto operator()(int16_t) { values_seen_.emplace_back(ScalarT{int16_t{1}}); }
  auto operator()(int32_t) { values_seen_.emplace_back(ScalarT{int32_t{2}}); }
  auto operator()(int64_t) { values_seen_.emplace_back(ScalarT{int64_t{4}}); }
  auto operator()(float) { values_seen_.emplace_back(ScalarT{float{8}}); }
  auto operator()(double) { values_seen_.emplace_back(ScalarT{double{16}}); }  

  auto Finalize() {
    return std::accumulate(values_seen_.begin(), values_seen_.end());
  }

private:
  std::vector<ScalarT> values_seen_;
};

int main() {
  auto v1 = ScalarT{int8_t{}};
  auto visitor1 = FooVisitor();
  std::visit(visitor1, v1);
  std::visit(visitor1, v1);
  auto f1 = visitor1.Finalize();
  std::cout << "Index of finalized values in visitor1: " << f1.index() << std::endl;

  auto v2 = ScalarT{int32_t{}};
  auto visitor2 = FooVisitor();
  std::visit(visitor2, v2);
  std::visit(visitor2, v2);
  auto f2 = visitor2.Finalize();
  std::cout << "Index of finalized values in visitor2: " << f2.index() << std::endl;  
}

This fails to compile given std::accumulate does not know what to do with a vector of variants:
visitor.cc: In member function ‘auto FooVisitor::Finalize()’:
visitor.cc:18:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘accumulate(std::vector<std::variant<signed char, short int, int, long int> >::iterator, std::vector<std::variant<signed char, short int, int, long int> >::iterator)’
   18 |     return std::accumulate(values_seen_.begin(), values_seen_.end());

Is there something I should be doing within my Finalize method call to get the accumulation to work with the variants? Or is this design pattern just completely unfit for what I am trying to accomplish?

Out of curiosity: why do you actually need a variant here (instead of simply storing int64_t always) ? The data frame with this variant will not occupy less memory even if it holds int8_t. A variant is usually useful when you want to store types that are really different like numbers and strings, or even integers and floating point values. But here they are all integral types anyway.

I think your example lost actual problem, since visitor wraps back to the same type visitor was unpacking. Curretly same problem can be repro by this, but I do not think this was your question.

@wohlstad in the real use case I am trying to solve the variant does include different integral sizes, floating point, strings, and some custom types that may make their way into the database. I wanted to try and keep this post simpler, but I can see why that is ambiguous. I'll add in floating types at least to make it less confusing

@marek R also an issue of trying to keep this simple. In the case of FooVisitor I am returning the same type, but as more algorithms get added that won't always be the case. A SumVisitor may want to return int64_t for all integral types, and double for floating point types. A MinVisitor may want to return the same type that is being visited. A MeanVisitor may return floating point when visiting both integral and floating point types, etc...

@WillAyd if your actual variant can contains e.g. both numbers and strings, how do you expect std::accumulate (which contains generic code) to behave with a vector of them ?

A single instance of the visitor should only ever deal with one type of the variant, which is likely an assertion that my code is not expressing at the moment. Essentially I am trying to do a MapReduce with each Visitor instance

Assuming you over complicated sample code here is possible solution: https://godbolt.org/z/G599Ysnrd https://godbolt.org/z/Wr6csWs9o

@MarekR your solution works also for the updated question with a variant that includes floating point values - see here. IMHO you should consider to post it as an answer (although the OP mentioned in a comment that in reality it may contain a string also or custom types, and I don't see how this general case can be handled).

Definitely an interesting solution. I think it will still work for other types / algorithms - would just need to define the proper overloads in the ScalarTAccumulate function for each algorithm.
However, the godbolt output shows the resulting variant type as an int32_t in both cases?

Isn't the reason your code doesn't compile much simpler? std::accumulate() expects at least three arguments. You are only supplying the range, not the init value.

That is a typo from the OP, although within the context of that Finish method I'm not sure what value you would use for the init value

For your case initial value can be .0L, because it's a double precision summation. But you need the forth argument too:[](auto a, auto b){ return a() + b(); }. But best is to use C++23 <ranges>: return std::ranges::fold_left(values_seen_, .0L, [](auto a){return a();});

From your comment "A single instance of the visitor should only ever deal with one type of the variant", I would say that std::variant is the wrong tool for your purpose.
template <typename T>
struct FooTraits;

template<> struct FooTraits<int8_t> { static constexpr int8_t value{0} }
template<> struct FooTraits<int16_t> { static constexpr int16_t value{1} }
template<> struct FooTraits<int32_t> { static constexpr int32_t value{2} }
template<> struct FooTraits<int64_t> { static constexpr int64_t value{4} }
template<> struct FooTraits<float> { static constexpr float value{8} }
template<> struct FooTraits<double> { static constexpr double value{16} }

template <typename T>
class FooVisitor {
public:
  auto operator()(T) { values_seen_.emplace_back(FooTraits<T>::value); }
  auto Finalize() {
    return std::accumulate(values_seen_.begin(), values_seen_.end());
  }

private:
  std::vector<T> values_seen_;
};

int main() {
  auto v1 = int8_t{};
  auto visitor1 = FooVisitor<int8_t>();
  visitor1(v1);
  visitor1(v1);
  auto f1 = visitor1.Finalize();

  auto v2 = int32_t{};
  auto visitor2 = FooVisitor<int32_t>();
  visitor2(v2);
  visitor2(v2);
  auto f2 = visitor2.Finalize();
}

At the very least, you should consider the difference between std::vector<std::variant<Ts...>> and std::variant<std::vector<Ts...>>

You might use std::visit with several variant
auto Finalize() {
    return std::accumulate(values_seen_.begin(),
                           values_seen_.end(),
                           ScalarT {int8_t{0}}
                           [](ScalarT acc, ScalarT value){
         return std::visit([](auto acc, auto value){ return ScalarT{acc + value}; }, acc, value);
     }
    );
}

Note: I let regular promotion happens, so int8_t+int8_t results in int, but you can handle it in the visit to have the type you expect
